# Как открыть 404.htm, если нет страницы с выбранным условием?

Tags: javascript

Этот код при нажатии на дату открывает страницу соответствующую выбранной дате

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(date) {
      $('#article').load(date + '.htm');
      $('#datepicker_value').val(date)
    }
  });
  $("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", $('#datepicker_value').val());
});
```

Как сделать, чтобы если нет страницы с выбранной датой, то открывать 404.htm?

Comment: во-первых не юзай расширение .htm

Comment: Почему? Что не так с HTM?

Comment: это не хорошо..

Comment: Вы разницу между этими расширениями понимаете?

Comment: ее нет, но .html читабильнее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(date) {
      $('#article').load(date + '.htm', function(response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "error") {
          location.href = '404.html';
        }
        $('#datepicker_value').val(date)
      });
    }
  });
  $("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", $('#datepicker_value').val());
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<input type="text" id="datepicker_value">

<div id="article"></div>
```